# HP StorageWorks Command View EVA 5.0 Problems

Tags: storage

I have a Proliant DL360 running Windows Server 2003 SP2.  The server is connected via fiber to an EVA 5000 storage system.  I want to use this server to manage the EVA and I installed HP StorageWorks Command View EVA 5.0.  Install was uneventful.  I open HP System Management Homepage 3.0.1.73, go to Webapps, and sometimes there is a link for `command_view_eva`, if not, I have to restart the command view eva service.  I click the link and get:

Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET/command_view_eva

Reason: Error reading from remote server

I'm running IE 6 SP2 with default settings
Internet Explorer Enhanced Security is enabled

Answer (score 2):

You might try going directly to the CommandView server itself, rather than through the System Homepage:

https://[servername]:2372/

That won't fix the proxy issue, but will allow you to manage your arrays.

Comment: I tried going to https://[servername]:2372/ and received "Page cannot be displayed error message"